# Total Item Count in a column within the same list

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, custom-list, count

I have a new request that I have to fulfill by Monday.
So I have been requested to get the total item count of list items in a share Point list which also has a condition to it, which is Items visible only to the person who created the item.

I also have a drop down which has two columns Available and consumed, I wanna get the total  count of list items of which are consumed and which are available in two different columns one for available and one for consumed.

So I need three columns which are:

- Total Count, Available Count, Consumed Count.

If you guys know how to do this, Please help me out.
Thank You.

Comment: Do you need it in the form using some jquery or in list view ? question is not much clear

Comment: i need it in a list view. There will be three columns which Total count, Available Count  and Consumed Count. I wanna populate these columns with count values in list view.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No need to create a three column to achieve your goal, Also the `Calculated Column` and `SharePoint Designer` does not help in this context!

---

**The simple OOTB workaround is**

- Create one view with the following settings

  - To filter with Created By User

[image]

- To Group By with the Status (Available/Consumed)

[image]

- To get the count for each status and the total count

[image]

## **[OutPut]**

[image]

Comment: I see that you have provided a very detailed answer and it seems a really easy solution. I just wanted to ask you only on the filter it shows the count for status items right. I also wanted to know the count of total list items if the above condition which is `Created by [Me]` is applied.

Comment: @jayantkhushalani Yes, it's right Please don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as accepted in case it helped you :) also don't hesitate to ask if you have any other related question!